# Indexing data from Azure to MongoDB and Elastic search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, azure-devops

Currently, data is available in Azure, how to index the data which is present in azure into MongoDB and Elastic search.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share more details. Which service on Azure do you try to index? Does it one-time indexing or repeated? How do the data look like? Which format (if it's a file)?

Comment: Hi Netanel Thanks for the reply... Data is already present in Data Late hosted in Azure. My requirement is how to transfer the data from Azure to MongoDB. MongoDB is hosted in On premises(internal application)

Comment: Is Elasticsearch not necessary?

Comment: yes on ingestion to MongoDB that will be indexed to Elastic search

Comment: Please take a look at that page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb?tabs=data-factory